# Creating dll files

Tags: c++, dll

How can we create a .dll file from an existing .cpp file?
I have my HelloWorld.cpp and HelloWorld.h file already created.

Please help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, what compiler (and version) are you using? I'm guessing MSVC++, so Dynamic Libraries are normally a built-in template (probably named 'Win32 DLL') you can use. (There is also 'Class Library', which is similar.)

Your header file signatures should probably also contain `__declspec(dllexport)` to make sure the compiler makes them visible.

Change the configuration type to 'Dynamic Library' (under Properties->Configuration Properties->General) and build.

Remember: DLL files are just normal plain old executables... They can contain a Main(), but they don't need to, just a collection of classes is also perfectly fine... You can often even simply rename .exe to .dll, though every compiler has its own little things...

A useful link might be: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's platform/compiler dependent. On Windows, with Microsoft Visual C++, you would say:

```
cl /LD HelloWorld.cpp
```